# Eclipse error "The file does not exist for the external tool named Maven_Ant_Builde"

Tags: java, eclipse, opensuse

I've just downloaded a project from Github and imported it into Eclipse.

I just want to compile it for now. However build fails for the above error. I'm not a great expert in Java compilation tools, but the error message suggests me that I'm missing something in my system :)

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'projectname'.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Maven_Ant_Builder.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Maven_Ant_Builder.
```

Running `zypper se maven` didn't report packages to install. I do already have `ant`

What should I install on my system in order to compile that project?